# Javascript swapping values

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, matrix, swap

I need to be able to go through a randomized 3 x 3 matrix and check to see if the numbers are in order (i.e. that the top row is 1-3, center 4-6 and bottom 7-9). So far i wrote this function in JS:

```
function winningorder(topleft, topcenter, topright, centerleft, centercenter, centerright, bottomleft, bottomcenter, bottomright){
if(document.getElementById(topleft).innerHTML = 1 && document.getElementById(topcenter).innerHTML = 2 && document.getElementById(topright).innerHTML = 3 && document.getElementById(centerleft).innerHTML = 4 && document.getElementById(centercenter).innerHTML = 5 && document.getElementById(centerright).innerHTML = 6 &&document.getElementById(bottomleft).innerHTML = 7 && document.getElementById(bottomcenter).innerHTML = 8 && document.getElementById(bottomright).innerHTML = 9){
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Well Done!"); }, 250);
}
```

I do not know if i need to put all the locations (the HTML id of each cell) as the parameters, so that is my first question. Secondly, where would i put my function in the HTML code. the code is:

```
<table border=1>
<tr class="numberrow">
    <td id="topleft" class="numbertile" onclick="processclick(this.id)" onchange=="winningorder(id)" ></td>
    <td id="topcenter" class="numbertile" onclick="processclick(this.id)" onchange=="winningorder(id)"></td>
    <td id="topright" class="numbertile" onclick="processclick(this.id)" onchange=="winningorder(id)"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="numberrow">
    <td id="centerleft" class="numbertile" onclick="processclick(this.id)" onchange=="winningorder(id)"></td>
    <td id="centercenter" class="numbertile" onclick="processclick(this.id)" onchange=="winningorder(id)"></td>
    <td id="centerright" class="numbertile" onclick="processclick(this.id)" onchange=="winningorder(id)"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="numberrow">
    <td id="bottomleft" class="numbertile" onclick="processclick(this.id)" onchange=="winningorder(id)"></td>
    <td id="bottomcenter" class="numbertile" onclick="processclick(this.id)" onchange=="winningorder(id)"></td>
    <td id="bottomright" class="numbertile" onclick="processclick(this.id)" onchange=="winningorder(id)"></td>
</tr>
```

My first though was to use an onchange event and run the function but that is not working. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Put `document.getElementById(tileId)` into a global variable, and use that in the `else` block.

Comment: as clicked cell appears to be a global already, rather than storing the innerHTML in clickedcell, store the element (and your if would be `if(!clickedcell)` for simplicity) - the rest should write itself

Comment: but if I'm trying to change the inside of the cell (the number in the cell), wouldn't i have to store that number somewhere? or how do i exactly write that code, im still stuck

Comment: Completely new problem I am having, solved my old one, would appreciate any help @JaromandaX

Comment: @Barmar you too

Comment: PS: Questions should be about a single, clear problem. Don't edit the question to replace it with something entirely new.

Comment: To answer your question. You need to define when and how is grid going to change. Is it html page generated by server side script?

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know if i need to put all the locations (the HTML id of each cell) as the parameters

No you don't have to. You'll receive event object with element that triggered a specific event (`event.target`) in your callback function (processclick).

```
function processclick(event) {
  var targetId = event.target.id;
}
```

> Secondly, where would i put my function in the HTML code. the code is:

Is hard to tell what are you trying to achieve, so probably this answer will be edited, but my guess is you're rendering your grid on a server and in javascript you're trying to verify it is valid. If so, the simplest way is to put javascript code after your html table code.

Full example (I've preferred code readability over performance):

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .numbertile {
        height: 5em;
        width: 5em;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <table border=1>
    <tr class="numberrow">
        <td id="topleft" class="numbertile">1</td>
        <td id="topcenter" class="numbertile">2</td>
        <td id="topright" class="numbertile">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="numberrow">
        <td id="centerleft" class="numbertile">4</td>
        <td id="centercenter" class="numbertile">5</td>
        <td id="centerright" class="numbertile">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="numberrow">
        <td id="bottomleft" class="numbertile">7</td>
        <td id="bottomcenter" class="numbertile">8</td>
        <td id="bottomright" class="numbertile">9</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <script>
    function winningorder() {
      //[id, innerHTML]
      var winningMap = {
        topleft: 1,
        topcenter: 2,
        topright: 3,
        centerleft: 4,
        centercenter: 5,
        centerright: 6,
        bottomleft: 7,
        bottomcenter: 8,
        bottomright: 9
      };
      var tilesEl = document.getElementsByClassName('numbertile');
      var isDone = Array.prototype.slice.call(
        tilesEl, 0
      ).every(function (el) {
        // the every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass
        // the test implemented by the provided function.
        return winningMap[el.id] === Number(el.innerHTML);
      });
      if (isDone) {
        setTimeout(function(){ alert("Well Done!"); }, 250);
      } else {
        setTimeout(function(){ alert("Try again!"); }, 250);
      }
    }
    winningorder();
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```